# some details in mapbox are not supported can i add it manually?

Tags: java, android, maps, mapbox, mapbox-android

I want to change from google maps API to Mapbox but some details and routes are missing in KSU campus I uploaded an image of comparison between google maps with lots with details and Mapbox, my question here can I add them manually using Mapbox API (routes and locations) and if I successfully do so, the routing still works perfectly?

[mapbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD6cm.jpg)

[google maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfavO.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox maps rely on data from [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org), a global volunteer project that everyone can contribute to. If you are familiar with this area in the KSU campus, I encourage you to go to [openstreetmap.org](https://www.openstreetmap.org), create an account, and make improvements directly. You'll have the option to go through an interactive tutorial to get you started. There are more details for advanced editing here as well: https://labs.mapbox.com/mapping. The Mapbox Streets tileset is updated regularly as features are edited or added to the map, which means that if you edit OpenStreetMap, you will eventually see your changes reflected on your Mapbox map.

These changes made to the road network in OSM will also be ingested by the [Mapbox Directions API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/#directions), so that you can use them when routing in your application.

Comment: Thank you very much! you saved me lots of time i have quick question, i want to make map app for blind users in KSU campus using Mapbox that position your location and gives you the routing to your destination turn by turn and tell you about the places in your way by voice, i want it to work in offline also, is it difficult to do? i'm beginner in this field, can you give summary on the things i will do like you can say mind map

Comment: Happy to help! That is definitely possible to do with Mapbox and I'd be happy to give you a conceptual overview of how to do it, but would you mind making a separate question so that there is more room to answer there? It will be helpful to answer in a question rather than a thread so there is more room for code, links, etc. Others might have similar questions too, and putting the question in its own post rather than a comment makes it more likely for other people to find in the future :)

Comment: Sure, I appreciate your help Adriana this is the post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60670343/how-to-build-map-app-navigation-using-mapbox-api

Comment: Hello Adriana do you face any problems accessing the post?

Comment: I posted a response on your other post.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it!