# How to Build Map app Navigation using MapBox API?

Tags: mapbox-android

I want to make map app for blind users in KSU campus using Mapbox API that position your location and gives you the routing to your destination turn by turn and tell you about the places in your way by voice. I want it to work in offline mode, also the user can search for his/her destination using keywords or by suggestions based on categories such as restaurants, faculties, etc. Do I need database, can you give me tips and summary on the things I will do like you can say conceptual overview? I would be grateful you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is quite a large task, I will give a conceptual overview. First, you will want to set up a basic Android application that displays a Mapbox map by following this [First Steps with the Mapbox Maps SDK for Android tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/first-steps-android-sdk/).

[This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-change-listening/) shows how to track and display device location. For step-by-step guidance, you can follow [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-change-listening/) to understand how to show the user's location on the map.

Next, you can use the [Mapbox Navigation SDK for Android](http://ps://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/) to compute and display routes to destinations. [This section](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/milestones/) of the documentation explains how to use voice instructions with navigation.

You can then use the [Mapbox Android Offline plugin](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/offline/) to integrate offline maps. [This guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/mobile-offline/) also provides a useful overview of offline maps, and [this Android example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/download-a-simple-offline-map/) shows how to implement a simple offline map.

The Mapbox Places plugin for Android][8](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/places/) lets users search for destinations. You can use this plugin to allow users to search for restaurants, facilities, etc. You might need your own database depending on what else you want to do and what information you want to include, since you might have some data in your database not included with the Places plugin. This will be specific to your implementation.

In general, going forward, I'd recommend that you search the [Mapbox documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/). The documentation is very detailed, and each of your questions outlined here can be answered using the documentation. Familiarizing yourself with the docs will make things faster in the long run!